Problem with multirow and long text
I am having a problem with multirow in my table. I have very long text in some of the cells. Here's the MWE:
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

% Essential packages
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, multirow, tabularray, siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

%% Ragged Tables
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % get rid of full justification, allow hyphenation
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % ditto
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{calc}     % for '\widthof' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{Research Questions, Themes, and Initial Coding}
    \label{table:Research Questions, Themes, and Initial Coding}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
        {@{} A{1.1in} A{0.7in} A{1.3in} @{}}
        \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Research Questions}} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Themes}} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Initial Coding by Criteria}} \\
        \midrule
            \multirow{3}{=}{RQ1: What are the challenges of visual inspection in grading abaca fibers?} & 
                \multirow{3}{=}{Visual Inspection Challenges} & 
                Mind Map by Keywords \\
        & & Challenges of Visual Inspection \\
        \cmidrule{1-3}
        \multirow{4}{=}{RQ2: What technological solution should be designed and developed to address this matter?} & 
            \multirow{4}{=}{Technological Solutions} & 
            Abaca Fiber Classification Systems \\
        & & Impact of Technological Solutions \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


How would I solve this issue? Most of the results focus on cells that span only one row so this will not apply here. As you can see, the text overlaps with the borders which is a problem visually as Word doesn't run into those problems. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

this should be tabular not tabularx, and why are you using multirow here? you do not have any vertical spanning entries. It is these spurious multirow that are forcing teh over-print.

There is. RQ1 and RQ2 has two items in Initial Coding by Criteria. The headers though are definitely a mistake on my part @DavidCarlisle.

oh yes, sorry, I wouldn't (ever) use multrow but here you are specifying a vertical span of 3 rows and only spanning two. Also your A column is identical to a standard p  as >{\arraybackslash} does nothing.

Oh I tried various tests since earlier attempts didn't center the text as I wanted. I did a lot of trial and error and nothing satisfied what I want, which led me to asking this question. Also, thanks for the clarification! I used the custom command as I saw an answer using that (albeit with an extra command to center the text which I removed since I didn't need it) @David Carlisle

I would suggest to switch to tabularray, which does not allow multiline cells to overflow their cell borders. Also, it allows you to separate cells content from their appearance, so the code looks tidier. It does require some learning though:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \caption{Research Questions, Themes, and Initial Coding}
    \label{table:Research Questions, Themes, and Initial Coding}
    \begin{booktabs}{
        colspec={Q[l,wd=1.5in]Q[l,wd=0.8in]Q[h,l,wd=1.6in]},
        row{1}={font=\bfseries},
        cell{1}{1-Z}={c},
        cell{2}{1-2}={r=2}{h},
        cell{4}{1-2}={r=2}{h},
    }
    \toprule
    Research Questions & Themes & Initial Coding by Criteria \\
    \midrule
    RQ1: What are the challenges of visual inspection in grading abaca fibers? & 
    Visual Inspection Challenges & 
    Mind Map by Keywords \\
    & & Challenges of Visual Inspection \\
    \midrule
    RQ2: What technological solution should be designed and developed to address this matter? & 
    Technological Solutions & 
    Abaca Fiber Classification Systems \\
    & & Impact of Technological Solutions \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{booktabs}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The result:


Nice! But can you add spacing between "Mind Map..." and "Challenges..." as well as "Abaca Fiber..." and "Impact..."?

You can add rows={rowsep=1pt}, to the options list for that.

I'll try that tomorrow. Thank you @Sergei Golovan!

It works! Finally, how would I center the themes column vertically @Sergei Golovan, just like in the sample in this question?

As you can guess, Q[l,wd=0.8in] makes the second column width 0.8 inches wide and left justified. Can you guess now how to change this to get it centered?

Gotcha but I meant vertical centering, not horizontal centering @Sergei Golovan.

The simplest solution is to add some extra vertical space:
Challenges of Visual Inspection \\[15pt]
...
Impact of Technological Solutions \\[15pt]

Otherwise, to get a completely automatic solution, consider using the tabularray package, but this requires a rewrite of the table.
Some remarks: (1) it isn't useful to use tabularx without any X type column. (2) Why use \cmidrule{1-3} instead of \midrule?

ohhh so it was fundamentally the same command, thanks for the clarification!
